# Word Documents Alignment Change in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there an issue within SharePoint 2013 Word Documents that the edits made after Checking Out don't stick? My problem is the alignment of objects don't remain after I save them.

Comment: So, if you check the document out, then both change the alignment of one or more objects and change some text, then save and check in, the text change sticks but the alignment change doesn't?

Comment: Many times the alignments of the photo box changes. I think this might be due to the fact that I don't select the correct Layout Options and then select  Fix Position On Page.